# Count (and activate) opened Word Documents

Tags: vba, excel

This is odd - I swear I was just using this code successfully, but not it's not working:

```
Sub t()
Dim wdApp As Object
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Debug.Print wdApp.Documents.Count
End Sub
```

From Excel, it should simply realize there is a Word document open, and return `1`.  However, I'm getting `0` for some reason.  I've also tried `Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application").`

What might I be overlooking? There are no errors thrown, it's just not showing I have a document open.

(Note: I got the idea from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005723/activate-word-window-from-excel-with-vba), as I want to copy an Excel range and paste into a Word doc.)

Comment: I'd check your task manager to see if you have a zombie Word process running.

Comment: @Comintern - Ooooooh, I have five "WINWORD.EXE" running.  This only works with one?  Edit: Yep, it works when I close all four zombies and have just one open.  Thanks a billion, this was a (thankfully) easy fix. If you wish to make that an answer, I'll mark it. Cheers!!

Comment: For your specific purpose, yes.  `GetObject` can only return one application object, so it looks like you're getting one without a document open.  I'm not sure off the top of my head which one it picks if there are multiple instances running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetObject` can only return one `Word.Application` object. If you have multiple instances running, the count of open documents might be off (because you're only counting from one instance).  Unfortunately it isn't clear from the documentation *which* application you get in this instance, but I'd guess you're getting 0 from `wdApp.Documents.Count` because you're attaching to a zombie Word process.

Answer (score 2):

Also as best practices, always free resources within error handling so such processes are always closed if macros succeeds or fails.

```
Sub t()
On Error Goto ErrHandle
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    Debug.Print wdApp.Documents.Count

    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

And if running COM interfaces from other languages such as Python, PHP, R, etc. use `try/catch` procedures to always clear such objects regardless of fail or success. Below is the counterpart of macro in Python:

```py
import win32com.client

try:
    wdApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    print(wdApp.Documents.Count)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:    
    wdApp = None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Sub t()
        Dim wdApp As Object
        Dim Docs
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Err.Number <> 424 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        
        Set Docs = wdApp.Documents
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "No Doc is open"
        Else
        MsgBox Docs.Count
        End If
        
        End Sub
```