# Format for automatically created Word documentation

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a spreadsheet in Excel that contains computer-generated documentation for a database. I have written some VBA to extract some of the columns and fold it together with my own hand-typed descriptions, producing a new Worksheet.

The result is only "semi" readable because Excel isn't the right format for reading. I'd like to translate this to Word, perhaps one page per table (there's about 25 tables in total). My idea is to make a document who's last page is just the formatting, which I would copy as needed for each following page.

I've seen a few descriptions of "search and replace" type solutions, one using bookmarks seemed like an interesting solution, but none of these address making new pages (or whatever) based on an existing page. Has anyone done something similar?

UPDATE: I've progressed slightly based on some code found elsewhere:

```
        wApp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:="3"              ' this is the template page
        wDoc.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy            ' copy it
        wApp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToLast      ' move to the end of the document
        wApp.Selection.Paste
```

Unfortunately, edit as I might, it always copies and pastes the first page, not page 3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2006077 might get you started.

Comment: That works fine for 1:1 replacements - one page in, one page out. But I have 1:n replacements.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I had posted on this. I finally found a working solution, although I am unhappy with how difficult Word makes this. Basically you can only *practically* build up a document by appending, so my code is a big loop over the input spreadsheet, and the guts of the loop looks like this:

```
wDoc.Characters.Last.Select
wApp.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7  'wdPageBreak
wDoc.Characters.Last.Select
wApp.Selection.InsertAfter Tn
wApp.Selection.Style = wDoc.Styles("Heading 2")
wDoc.Characters.Last.Select
wApp.Selection.InsertAfter " (Table: " & WT.Cells(R, 2) & ")"
wApp.Selection.Style = wDoc.Styles("Heading 4")
wDoc.Characters.Last.Select
wApp.Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf
wDoc.Characters.Last.Select
wApp.Selection.InsertAfter (WT.Cells(R, 3))
wApp.Selection.Style = wDoc.Styles("No Spacing")
wDoc.Characters.Last.Select
wApp.Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf
wApp.Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf
```

You can see the basic logic, you have to keep inserting parts at the end, pulling bits from the sheet and InsertAfter. Styles are a pain due to the way Word figures where they start and end. Anyway, this does work.