# Sending VARIABLES from EXCEL to WORD

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, excel-2003

I have this complex **excel** file that calls (opens) a **doc** file.

Now I want to be able to change a few part of the **word** file (no formatting change just the strings).

***What I'm think of doing is:***

1. The **excel** file creates a **txt** file with each line
   representing the **"vars"** I want send to **word**.
2. On opening word, the **DOC** execs a macro that reads each line form
   the **txt** and does a REPLACE for that **var**.

I'm think of having the **vars** on the **doc** like this:

Bla bla bla bla **?!-1-!?**  bla bla bla bla .... ?!-2-!?

Where **?!-1-!?** and **?!-2-!?** are the vars to replaced for lines 1 and 2 from the **txt** file

***My questions are***:

1. Is this stupid?
2. Is there a better way?
3. and most importantly, is there a easier way?

***Also***: I'm good in vba for **excel 2003**, newbie on vba for **word 2003**. Any links on help with working with files on **vba word**?

***TL;DR:*** Easiest way to send text variables form excel to word

Comment: I don't have time to test it now, but I'm pretty sure you can somehow call the macro in word and there passing the variables. Something like `wordApp.Run "yourMacro(" & yourVar & ")".

Comment: Just use OLE (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184974) and run it all from Excel. See this answer for good links: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7523102/1733206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is a good one but this is what you might use when the application you want to send information to does not "allow access".  The good thing about MS Office is you do get to automate it.  So I would suggest you automate Word from your Excel.

First you should add a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library" in your Excel project.
Second to get word you would need something like this in your excel code.

```
On Error Resume Next
   Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   If Err.Number = 429 Then
      'Word is not running; creating a Word object
      Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      Err.Clear
   End If
```

Next to get your word document something like this;

```
Set objDocs = objWord.Documents
objDocs.add("Path to your Word Documenbt")
Set myDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
```

Next I choose to use CustomDocumentProperties

```
Set prps = objWord.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
prps.item("YourCustomName").Value = "Your Variable from Excel"
```

The hard bit is setting up your word document so here are a few links or tutorials on what I have suggested here.

[How to add CustomDocumentProperties](http://www.syschat.com/how-create-custom-document-properties-word-6626.html)
[Microsoft Example of how to use CustomDocumentProperties in VBA](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/MixedDocProps.htm)

Answer (score 1):

1. I would not say it is stupid. It's one of the possible ways of tackling this problem :)
2. Probably there is a better way...
3. Probably there is an easier way...

...unfortunately I can't give you the actual code. 
But I suggest you go to Tools > References, and Enable 'Microsoft Word Object Library'. If you explore Word library I believe you will be able to find a neat way to transfer that data between those applications. 
You may also check the following link:
[Copy Text from Range in Excel into Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006077/copy-text-from-range-in-excel-into-word-document)

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked up Mail Merge in MS Word? Try to imagine the data from your Excel spreadsheet filling in a form letter in MS Word. From your description, it sounds like your vars in Word could be translated into Mail Merge fields. The data for the fields seems to be stored in the Excel spreadsheet.

If Mail Merge is what you are looking for, you can store multiple iterations of your data on separate lines and use Words' Mail Merge query function to print/prepare only what you need.